# Are there bounded monotone sequences whose product is not monotone?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was wondering whether or not the product of two monotone and bounded sequences must be monotone. I can think of e.g. $(x_n)=(-1,-1,1,1,1,…)$ and $(y_n)=(1,0,-1,-1,-1,…)$ that are clearly both monotone and bounded but their product isn’t, since we have (-1,0,-1,-1,…). The only problem is that that sequence is *eventually* monotone. So, are there monotone bounded sequences whose product is not even eventually monotone?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Product of bounded monotone functions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2239678/product-of-bounded-monotone-functions)

Answer (score 1):

No, take $x$ and $y$ defined by $x_n = x_{n+1} = 1/n$ and $y_n = y_{n-1} = 1-1/n$ if $n$ is even. Then $x$ is increasing, but constant when passing from even to odd, $y$ is decreasing but constant when passing from odd to even. Hence $x_n\,y_n$ is not monotone.

If you want $x$ to be strictly monotone, you can always add a very tiny perturbation when going from even to odd, such as $x_{n+1} = 1/n - 1/(100 n^2)$, and similarly for $y$.